# Should we take the OP's English level into account when answering?

Tags: discussion, english

Let's say there's an interesting question that's written in poor English. It goes without saying that we can (and probably should) edit the question to increase its quality and make it more readable for future readers. But the fact remains that the OP's grasp of English might be poor.

If we decide to answer a question like that, how should we handle this issue? Is it best to attempt to keep the wording of our answers as simple as possible (in the style of the [Simple English version of Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)), even if it sacrifices some conceptual clarity? Or should we strive to write an answer that is as thorough and technical as we'd like it to be, even though it may not be fully understood by the OP?

(Obviously I'm not a native English speaker either and my own grasp of the language may be poor as well, so I'm definitely not trying to sound condescending here.)

---

If you need an example, the SO question that inspired this Meta question can be found here [in its original form](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37376258/1), [after my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37376258/4) and this is [my attempt to answer it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37378591/1892179).

Comment: Since when is the answer just for the OP. obviously, don't make it more cryptic than it has to be, but in general, questions are just vehicles to get answers for the site. Focus on writing your answer for the greater audience (if you have the time and feel nice, add a section summarizing on simper terms. But i say the complex, more complete answer should be priority 1)

Comment: "Obviously I'm not a native English speaker"...not obvious at all, actually; the text of this question is fluent.

Comment: The only indication that you are not a native speaker is that you are a cat... Otherwise "sacrifices some conceptual clarity" is way above average English. You may need to use some region-specific words to even give a hint of "not a native English speaker".

Comment: somewhat related: [Our words are too complicated. Let's make them simpler!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269289/165773)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I had no clue that OP was non-native, and I am a native English speaker.

Comment: Simple English wiki is a bad example here. I don't exactly know its purpose, but from pages I have seen it simplifies not only language but the matter also. At SO people might have poor English but they are supposed to know well the programming.

Comment: The only clue we have that you and I are not native English speakers, is your (and my) name. You are probably a native Greek speaker, and I am probably a native Dutch speaker. It's a common occurrence that non-native English speakers use above average English, especially in writing, because they need to think more before they write. That's my theory about how non-native speakers make less mistakes against their/they're/there.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that people who start their posts by apologizing for their poor English, invariably have nothing to apologize for?

Comment: @AlanMoore Nope. There are plenty of questions in poor English containing apologies.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is far harder to express yourself while writing in English, than it is to read proper English written by someone else. Everyone is better at reading English than writing English, because the latter is harder. (Same goes for speaking versus listening.)

Comment: Bravo on that edit BTW. You did a stellar job. I couldn't read more than the first few paragraphs of the original, but found myself genuinely interested in the post after your edit.

Comment: I was of the mind that the OP is the *primary* audience. If you respond in a way that the OP won't get, it will disrupt further dialogue and that won't do the secondary/general audience any good.

Comment: What you're effectively asking is should Stack Overflow adopt the use of something like [Simplified Technical English](http://www.asd-ste100.org/) as an official/required language.

Comment: How about creating a separate Stack Overflow in Simple English?

Comment: Google Translate is perfectly capable of translating complex English into the OP's native language.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

### No.

Answer with future visitors in mind. Not just for the OP.

Just use normal "everyday" English, and make your answer as complete as possible. Don't simplify your answer for the sake of *one* user.

Comment: Side note: People learn a language by using it and practising it. Not by reading dumbed down posts.

Comment: Agreed. According to http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error, one of the requirements for asking and/or answering is:  "Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability."

Comment: It's also worth noting that most people's reading ability is greater than their writing ability.

Comment: The OP can always ask for clarification in comments below the answer...

Comment: I don't see any problem in use words that would be easier to understand for a bigger audience. The problem is "dumbfy" the answer losing anything that would be useful.

Comment: if you feel bad, you can always add a comment to your answer that is your answer in simpler terms

Answer (score 102):

### Do be mindful of it, don't dumb anything down

Most non-native English speakers are much better at understanding texts than they are at writing them. So they will probably be able to understand your answer if you write it in non-simplified English.

That said, because many users of this site are non-native English speakers, I'd recommend not intentionally using complicated language. And I'd avoid uncommon words or slang terms that aren't related to the technology in question. For example, "dependency injection" and "debugging" are pretty obscure terms to most English learners, but should be familiar to most programmers.
But the same people won't necessarily know what words like "fastidious" or phrases like "to your heart's content" mean.

Comment: _*Googles `fastidious`*_. There I was thinking I knew English :D

Comment: So, we should be fastidious regarding our avoidance of idiomatic phraseology? What's a poor sesquipedalian to do?

Comment: Avoid obfuscation, be perspicuous.

Comment: @CodyGray Verily, a vexatious plight unbeknownst by ones of adventitious filiation. Then again, such allegiance to acroamatic locutions is quixotic and a incensing display of superciliousness.

Comment: Is official: I know no English

Comment: @MKII *an <feels superior>

Comment: @WarrenP Eschew obfuscation.

Comment: @Jason Damnit, I knew I should've checked it more thoroughly!

Comment: @bkul Forswear befogging.

Comment: Oh, I've known that for years @Braiam :p You should set me to be your official certification authority.

Comment: Very important point! Don't use complicated words in an obvious attempt to sound smart! The goal is to be understood by as many people as possible without dumbing down the intent/concept.

Answer (score 25):

Not a native speaker? I am impressed. Most people born and raised where I live in the United States don't have anywhere near the lingual fluidity that you have displayed. 
To answer your question, most people I have met who are trying to learn English often are frustrated that everyone speaks to them in simple words and terms, because their goal is to learn the language to its fullest, not to get by with the basic points understood. Always answer as completely and accurately as possible, even if it means that the OP might need to look up a word or two. Chances are that some native speakers will need to look up a word too, if you answered as accurately as possible.

Comment: I'm not a grammar stickler but many American speakers use it's (it's fullest) where its should be used :)

Comment: FTFY. Use `it's` *only* when you can substitute `it is` in its (haha) place. The possessive word `its` (*this is its missing part*) does not have an apostrophe.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm a native speaker and I *still* use a rule to remember. *None* of these use an apostrophe: his, hers, its.

Comment: Not exactly a grammar Nazi, but it has always bothered me when people use apostrophes out of place. Usually they do so with plural words, it seems.

Answer (score 21):

## No

And I'll add another reason than the previous posters of negative answers:

Reading English is what developers do for a living. Being it MSDN, JavaDocs, this site or just normal books, we have a lot of practice doing that. *Writing* correct English is a whole different beast. That's hard because we never do that. It's rare that we actually *speak* English and that post on SO might be the only instance where the poster needed to generate proper sentences all by his own. So peoples' reading comprehension should be *a lot* better than their writing.

Don't expect people to not understand written English just by their proficiency to write English themselves. Even if they don't, looking things up in dictionaries is a *lot* easier from foreign to local than the other way round.

Simplifying is stripping information. I'm not here to lose information. So if we want to help non-native English speakers (and I'm one of them, so thanks in advance), we should write normal and above all **correct** English. *That* is really helpful.

Answer (score 12):

**NO** (IMHO)

English is not my first language but I don't want/expect a "light" answer in SO because of that... and probably the other 99% of people that read the answer use English as first language.

I understand the intention and is nice :-) but the [Lingua Franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) of Internet is English. If one OP doesn't understand the answer... his responsability is improving his level.

Answer (score 6):

**Keep your answers as simply worded and structured as reasonably possible in general.**

Your answers, while directed at the asker, are still intended to be generally consumable for others with the same issue. As such, you should configure your language to be as clear as possible to the general audience. Who the asker is should not factor into the structure of your answer.

You shouldn't *dumb down* answers just because you feel the asker has a weaker grasp of the language. Instead, you should strive to present the necessary content in the most easily-accessible and most user-friendly manner possible.

To that end, I argue shorter, more concise, more simply-worded answers are better than ones which are needlessly complex.

- They take less time to read and skim
- They are more likely to remain up-to-date if they have less extraneous information
- They will reach a wider audience *no matter* the asker's English level

I personally have a propensity to write long, rambling sentences with complex grammar, and I am certain that has hurt me here several times. I have also skipped answers (and questions) that may have been related to what I was doing because they gave me flashbacks to Tolkien's tree chapters.

So my advice, from personal experience on both sides, is **keep it simple, period**.

Comment: This is the philosophy I use in my own answers - make it as accessible as possible without leaving out any important information. It's a fine balance. If someone else leaves a more thorough answer than my own, I'll upvote it. If the OP has trouble understanding, comments can help.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach would be to **do both**. As the previous answers point out, your answer needs to be useful to all future viewers, not just the user who asked the question, so you need to include all the detail you can.

However, there is no reason why you can't either structure your answer so the the simple easy to understand points are made first. Or you could add a TL; DR summary at the end that you think a non-English speaker will understand.

Comment: I normally try to put my tl drs at the end of posts. Simply because i don't want users to "grab n run" while missing nuances

Answer (score 4):

Don't dumb anything down, even if *you* think it makes it easier to understand. It won't necessarily be simpler for the reader.

**On simplifying language structure:** Don't forget that there are automatic tools that are reasonable (at best, though improving daily) at translating correctly formed sentences. However try writing some form of pidgin in google translate, and pure gibberish comes out.

Whenever you're in the phase of struggling to express yourself in a new language, you already have decent comprehension skills. But nothing is harder to understand than over-simplified language. I would know, I've learned a couple languages myself, and what people remove to simplify language is what they, as someone fluent in that language, consider superfluous. However those can be important contextual clues to beginners -- especially from different cultures.

**The same applies to individual complicated words**: they can be looked up. If you replace them with a quasi-correct simpler word, your answer is less precise and it will be harder to understand, for the wider audience at least, and probably even for the OP.

Look at the Simple English Wikipedia front page (since you give it as example, emphasis mine):

> This is the front page of the Simple English Wikipedia. Wikipedias are
>   *places* where people work together to write encyclopedias in different
>   languages.

The word place is overly dumbed down, and the description becomes vague. Calling it a website, and having people look that up if they don't know what it is, would be a better approach. Especially for SO where you expect content to be technically useful.

The only thing I think you may try to avoid are slang, idioms, or obscure words (as covered by KWeiss).